# Align multiple gathered equations by symbol

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

I have something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \begin{gathered}
        abc + cde = \\
        xyz
    \end{gathered} \\
    \begin{gathered}
        c + de = \\
        uvw
    \end{gathered} \\
    \begin{gathered}
        ef + fgh = \\
        bcd
    \end{gathered}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

giving
[image]

Is there a way of aligning the plus symbols (like doing `&+`) so that they're directly under each other while keeping the `xyz`, `uvw` and `bcd` in the center (or at least centered by the `abcd + cde =` etc. above them)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: What do you mean by compilable? It's a properly indented piece of LaTeX code.

Comment: Start the code with `\documentclass` and end the code with `\end{document}` ...

Answer (score 3):

`split` is designed to group lines while maintaining alignment from an outer align. It only supports one such point though, I aligned on = here you could instead align on +

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        abc+ cde ={}& \\
        &xyz
    \end{split} \\
    \begin{split}
        c + de ={}& \\
        &uvw
    \end{split} \\
    \begin{split}
        ef + fgh ={}& \\
        &bcd
    \end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose this , based on `mathtools` and `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1][r]{$\displaystyle #2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
        abc &+   \eqmathbox{cde} = &  &  \\[-1ex]  \ArrowBetweenLines*[xyz]
        c  &+ \eqmathbox{de} =  &  &  \\[-1ex]  \ArrowBetweenLines*[uvw]
        ef &+  \eqmathbox{fgh} =  &  &   \\[-1ex]   \ArrowBetweenLines*[bcd]\notag
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]